# why does unordered set mix the values

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I am trying to remove duplicates from an vector by using an unordered_set. but my design creates an unordered_set that doesn't maintain the ordering correctly. in this example the "z" is not at the end. What am I doing wrong? thank you in advance.

EDIT: sorry if I wasn't clear with what I was looking for. I want the output to be "e,d,a,b,c,z" I want to keep original ordering but remove duplicates. I currently have it working using about 3 different for loops and an extra copy of the init vector. I was just looking for a STL function that was cleaner if possible.

output produced:
e d a b c a a a a b b b b c z
printing unordered set
e d a z b c

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iterator>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string>terminals = { "e", "d", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b","b", "b", "b", "c", "z" };
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = terminals.begin(); it != terminals.end(); it++) // print given vector
        cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;
    unordered_set<string> newSet;
    copy(terminals.begin(), terminals.end(), inserter(newSet, newSet.end()));
    cout << "printing unordered set" << endl;
    for (unordered_set<string>::iterator it = newSet.begin(); it != newSet.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's an _unordered_ set... what were you expecting? : ) Perhaps use an _ordered_ set instead?

Comment: Why would you expect an *unordered* set to have some kind of ordering?

Comment: unoredered_set == set that lacks any ordering == elements can be in any order and change order

Comment: @Jared this question is still listed as unanswered. Did none of the answers help?

Answer (score 5):

[std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set):

> Internally, **the elements are not sorted in any particular order**, but
>   organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
>   entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to
>   individual elements, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the
>   exact bucket the element is placed into.

If you need the unique terminals to be ordered, use a [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string>terminals = { "e", "d", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b","b", "b", "b", "c", "z" };

    for(const std::string& terminal : terminals) // print given vector
        std::cout << terminal << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";;

    // populate the set directly from the vectors iterators:
    std::set<std::string> newSet(terminals.begin(), terminals.end());;

    std::cout << "printing the (ordered) set:" << "\n";;
    for(const std::string& terminal : newSet)
        std::cout << terminal << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";;
}
```

If you want to maintain the *original* order, you can't use either set as your final storage, but you can use a `std::unordered_set` as a cache/blacklist for values you've already inserted in your final storage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string>terminals = { "e", "d", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b","b", "b", "b", "c", "z" };

    for(const std::string& terminal : terminals) // print given vector
        std::cout << terminal << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";;

    std::vector<std::string> newSet; // not really a set anymore
    std::unordered_set<std::string> cache; // blacklist

    // try to insert all terminals and only when an insert is successful,
    // put the terminal in newSet

    std::for_each(terminals.begin(), terminals.end(),
        [&](const std::string& terminal) {
            auto [it, inserted] = cache.insert(terminal);
            if(inserted)
                newSet.push_back(terminal);
        }
    );

    std::cout << "printing the vector of unique terminals:" << "\n";;
    for(const std::string& terminal : newSet)
        std::cout << terminal << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";;
}
```

If you want the original order *and* don't mind making changes directly to the original `terminals` vector, you can use `std::remove_if` combined with an `unordered_set` which is nice since it doesn't require a new vector. This is an annotated variant of @Marek R's answer:

Read this first: [Erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string>terminals = { "e", "d", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b","b", "b", "b", "c", "z" };

    for(const std::string& terminal : terminals) // print given vector
        std::cout << terminal << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";;

    std::unordered_set<std::string> cache; // blacklist

    // remove_if() moves all entries in your container, for which the
    // UnaryPredicate(*) returns true, to the end of the container. It returns
    // an iterator pointing to the first element in the vector that was
    // moved - which is a suitable starting point for a subsequent erase().
    //
    // (*) UnaryPredicate: A callable that returns true or false given a single
    //                     value.

    // auto past_new_end = std::vector<std::string>::iterator past_new_end
    auto past_new_end = std::remove_if(terminals.begin(), terminals.end(),
        // this lambda is the UnaryPredicate
        [&](const std::string& terminal) {
            // insert returns a std::pair<Iterator, bool>
            // where the bool (.second in the pair) is false
            // if the value was not inserted (=it was already present)
            return cache.insert(terminal).second == false;
        }
    );

    std::cout << "display all the entries (now with unspecified values) "
                 "that will be erased:\n";
    std::copy(past_new_end, terminals.end(),
                            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "<"));
    std::cout << "\n";

    // erase all the moved entries
    terminals.erase(past_new_end, terminals.end());

    std::cout << "printing the unique terminals:" << "\n";;
    for(const std::string& terminal : terminals)
        std::cout << terminal << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to use a [(ordered) set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/).

Edit : Looks like you don't, actually. A `std::vector` could work, but it's probably not the cleanest workaround.

Comment: Does not look like they want to use an ordered set. The ordered set doesn't keep the order in which elements are inserted. It keeps an order based on a relation operation.

Comment: @eerorika Didn't think of it that way, I stupidely assumed they wanted to order it alphabetically. A vector could work then.

Comment: It's understandable. The question isn't very clear about what order they were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the original order, but enforce uniqueness, you probably want to:

1. read in an item.
2. Try to insert it into the set
3. if that succeeds, it wasn't previously in the set, so also copy it to the output
4. Repeat

If you want the outputs ordered (so, in you example, the output would be "a b c d e z"), then you could either insert the items in an `std::set`, or else you could use `std::sort` followed by `std::unique` to get exactly one of each unique element in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an [unordered map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and then store the item as as key to the map and the index as the corresponding value to that key.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to remove duplicates from an vector by using an unordered_set.

Why do you assumed that `unordered_set` conserves any kind of order?
Name clearly states that there is no any particular order.

You should use `unordered_set` only to keep track if item was already found in sequence. Based on that you can remove item from sequence, so this should go like this:

```
void removeDuplicates(Data &data)
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> foundItems;
    auto newEnd = std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [&foundItems](const auto &s)
                                 {
                                     return !foundItems.insert(s).second;
                                 });
    data.erase(newEnd, data.end());
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/T24UfiLQep0XUQhQ

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: No need to check count before inserting, insert returns a bool if the value already existed